# Recursive query to produce edges of a path?

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, join, recursive-query

I have a table `paths`:

```
CREATE TABLE paths (
    id_travel INT,
    point INT,
    visited INT
);
```

Sample rows:

```
 id_travel | point | visited 
-----------+-------+---------
        10 |   35  |       0
        10 |   16  |       1
        10 |   93  |       2
         5 |   15  |       0
         5 |   26  |       1
         5 |  193  |       2
         5 |   31  |       3
```

And another table `distances`:

```
CREATE TABLE distances (
    id_port1 INT,
    id_port2 INT,
    distance INT CHECK (distance > 0),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_port1, id_port2)
);
```

I need to make a view:

```
 id_travel | point1 | point2 | distance 
-----------+--------+--------+---------
        10 |   35   |     16 |  1568
        10 |   16   |     93 |  987
         5 |   15   |     26 |  251
         5 |   26   |    193 |  87
         5 |  193   |     31 |  356
```

I don't know how to make `dist_trips` by a recursive request here:

```
CREATE VIEW dist_view AS
WITH RECURSIVE dist_trips (id_travel, point1, point2) AS 
   (SELECT ????)
SELECT dt.id_travel, dt.point1, dt.point2, d.distance
FROM dist_trips dt
NATURAL JOIN distances d;
```

`dist_trips` is a recursive request witch and should return three columns: `id_travel`, `point1`, and `point2` from table `paths`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need recursion. Can be plain joins:

```sql
SELECT id_travel, p1.point AS point1, p2.point AS point2, d.distance 
FROM   paths p1
JOIN   paths p2 USING (id_travel)
LEFT   JOIN distances d ON d.id_port1 = p1.point
                       AND d.id_port2 = p2.point
WHERE  p2.visited = p1.visited + 1
ORDER  BY id_travel, p1.visited;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4710a81372bf131af0d310efadf86b93)*

Your paths seem to have gapless ascending numbers. Just join each point with the next.

I threw in a `LEFT JOIN` to keep all edges of each path in the result, even if the `distances` table should not have a matching entry. Probably prudent.

Your `NATURAL JOIN` didn't go anywhere. Generally, `NATURAL` is rarely useful and breaks easily. [The manual warns:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN)

> `USING` is reasonably safe from column changes in the joined relations
> since only the listed columns are combined. `NATURAL` is considerably
> more risky since any schema changes to either relation that cause a
> new matching column name to be present will cause the join to combine
> that new column as well.